# Using Intelligencia UrlRewriter regex for rewriting URLs

Tags: asp.net, regex, urlrewriter.net

I'm trying to use regex expressions to catch some incoming urls, but I'm having trouble putting the right expression together.

Basically I'm trying to rewrite

> mydomain.com/abc12

into

> mydomain.com/default.aspx?referrer=abc12

The extension will always be a 5 character `[a-z0-9]` code, and I can't work out how to match only that specific combination. Anything I write seems to catch all my CSS files and everything as well.

Really I just need to grab that 5 char code, so if you have other suggestions as to how to do that I'm open to other recommendations as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to describe the pattern you want to find as good as possible

Maybe something like this:

```
mydomain\.com/([a-z0-9]{5})$
```

The quantifier `{5}` enforces exactly 5 characters and the anchor `$` enforces the end of the string after your code.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vlik)

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. It seems to just be the $ at the end that I missing. So this seems to be working now:
<rewrite url="~/([a-z0-9]{5})$" to="~/default.aspx?referrer=$1" />